# On Click Listener is Greyed Out

Tags: java, android

Hello Im a newbie in Java android app development I was just wondering why this is on click listener is greyed out and the button is not working?
thanks!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mFullname = findViewById(R.id.fullName);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
    mPhone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
    mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.regButton);


    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }



    // restriction  XML

    **mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {** this one is greyed out
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

Comment: It probably greyed out because IDE is indication an option that it can be converted to a lambda.

Comment: hi! thanks! is there any work around? like to disable this "Lambda" thing? or workaround script to replace? sorry Im studying it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable lambdas in two ways:

- disable Inspection for Lambda suggestions
- add/change your "build.gradle" by lowering JAVA version (but if you use other newer Java feature you cannot do this)

To lower JAVA version you need to add/change your "build.gradle" with:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    ...
}
```

Starting from VERSION_1_8 lambdas are allowed to be used.